# Как получить данные из ячейки в формате excel?

Tags: java

Дана таблица формата excel.
В первом столбце написаны баллы по экзаменам, а во втором и третьем два класса.
Как сделать так чтобы вводились номер класса и результат после чего выводило результат экзамена?
Ниже представлен код, который печатает всю таблицу excel.
Кто сможет подсказать хотя бы идею как сделать, буду благодарен.

```
public class excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Super Sany\\IdeaProjects\\asd\\Сила.xlsx"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
            if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();
                    switch (cellType) {
                        case _NONE:
                            System.out.print("");
                            System.out.print("\t");
                            break;
                        case BOOLEAN:
                            System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            System.out.print("\t");
                            break;
                        case BLANK:
                            System.out.print("");
                            System.out.print("\t");
                            break;
                        case FORMULA:
                            System.out.print(cell.getCellFormula());
                            System.out.print("\t");
                            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
                            System.out.print(evaluator.evaluate(cell).getNumberValue());
                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            System.out.print("\t");
                            break;
                        case STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            System.out.print("\t");
                            break;
                        case ERROR:
                            System.out.print("!");
                            System.out.print("\t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Задача абсолютно непонятна.  Приведите пример входного excel-файла, пример данных, введенных пользователем, и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Нужно описать чертеж объекта, где входные данные из эксель будут поля одной строки, дальше поместить это всё в коллекцию, и по запросу выдавать результат.